# Goolge Colab file upload not uploading the csv file

Tags: csv, upload, google-colaboratory

Ran the following code in Colab:

```
uploaded = files.upload()
```

Clicked "Choose Files" and selected the csv I want to upload.

But the file is not being uploaded. It worked once before but not again. All videos I watch about how to upload csv's locally, once the file is selected, Colab uploads the file immediately.

Colab is not doing that in my case. It's just sitting stagnant like this:

[stagnant colab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4yYV.png)

Comment: What browser and browser version are you using? How large is the CSV file?

Comment: Running Chrome 72 and the file is just under 16mb

Answer (score 0):

This is a Colab bug --
https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/437

The team reports they are working on a service change to correct the problem today. (21 Feb, 2019)

Answer (score 0):

Well even i had the same probem
you can also go for other option
1. In left pane of google colab there is a tab called **Files** Click on that.
2. click on the **upload** files. 
Thats it!!!! Pretty Simple Enough!!!!

for more details :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0rygVrmHidg

Answer (score 0):

Upload the file from the local machine using the following command:

```
from google.colab import files
import pandas as pd

uploaded = files.upload()

for fn in uploaded.keys():
  print('User uploaded file "{name}" with length {length} bytes'.format(
      name=fn, length=len(uploaded[fn])))
```

After that read the csv/text file using the pandas:

```
dataFrame= pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. I use this method. Upload the file from the google drive using the following command:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

data = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/Myfiles/datafiles/mydata.csv', delimiter=",")
```